# How to read large datasets from csv into dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, csv

> Error Encountered: ParserError: Error tokenizing data. C error: out of memory

Tried with smaller csv files and it works but not for larger files

```
import pandas as pd
LARGE_FILE =r'E:\Users\celine_chua\Downloads\flights.csv'


mylist2 = []
for chunk in  pd.read_csv(LARGE_FILE, sep=',', chunksize=1000):
    mylist2.append(chunk)

flights_df = pd.concat(mylist2, axis= 0)
del mylist2
```

Comment: I would first read in around 10k rows into your CSV then find out what the dtypes are and see if you can convert some of the string columns into category data types. From what I understand, pandas attempts to guess the data types of the columns which is very memory inefficient and declaring the data types, as well as the format for datetime columns is much better.

Comment: You could specify dtypes and use int32 or float32 or even int16 if possible , depending on the size of the data.

Comment: You can try [dask](https://docs.dask.org/en/latest/) library to load large csv file. It could help.